# Input on postback are blank

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am using jquery UI modal popup to show user login form.
The script adds html elements around the form to build the popup.

When i submit the login form - the textboxes appear to be empty in the code behind, even though I have entered the value in it.

I think it is because the input is moved from the original position it was rendered, thus the code somehow validates the request.

Question is: Is there a way to make the values pass thru any way? Or to disable this validation?

Example of code:

HTML:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="UI-login.aspx.cs" Inherits="tests_UI_login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.8.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.Application.add_load(function (sender, args) {

                    // Dialog       
                    $('#loginDialog').dialog({
                        autoOpen: true,
                        width: 600,
                        resizable: false,
                        modal: true,
                        show: 'slide',
                        hide: 'slide'


                    });})
    </script>
    <div id="loginDialog">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnLogin" runat="server" onclick="btnLogin_Click1">Login</asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

C# :

```
public partial class tests_UI_login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnLogin_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string email = txtEmail.Text; //Here the value is empty
    }
}
```

Comment: Well explained but it would be better to see the isolated code and any other associated code...

Comment: Are you doing anything with input element on JS side ? Also check your     Request.Form on Server side.

Comment: @Xander Just posted an example of code...

Comment: @dotnetstep I do nothing with the input at this stage

Comment: problem is with form and dialog. When you use dialog it keep your login div out of form1. In order to ASPX form work you need form1 with runat="Server" should wrap your text control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body>


<div id="loginDialog">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnLogin" runat="server" onclick="btnLogin_Click1">Login</asp:LinkButton>

    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Sys.Application.add_load(function (sender, args) {

            // Dialog       
            $('#loginDialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                width: 600,
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                show: 'slide',
                hide: 'slide'


            });
        })
</script>
    </div>
</body>
```

I did something like above it works. I kept form1 inside dialog.

Comment: You are right it does take the inputs out of the form. Unfortunately putting the entire form inside the popup is not an option, as the form sits on master page and i need just few fields to display in the popup. I'll probably add a line of script that will put it back inside the form tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To get the values of the inputs in the code behind and access them through the server controls mechanism (`textBox.Text`), their state (and presence) needs to be persisted in the ViewState. Since you are building them with javascript, their state is not persisted, the only way you can get their values is using the Request.Form collection.

As usual, posting the relevant code, may produce more specific answers.

Comment: `textBox.Text` would throw a compile-time error. So, he is not adding input fields through script. Most likely some other "decorative" HTML. That is why the OP needs to post some code...

Comment: I'm having a hard time reproducing this. `textEmail.Text` has a value when I enter something and click Login. I have a breakpoint set in the click handler, everything seems to work fine.

Comment: @Tomislav Markovski Did you put jquery ui script along with the test page?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are several issues, quickest solution would be to use an existing plugin, like the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).

Comment: i'm afraid i can use only one form element on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Just add the dialog to the form.

See http://labs.kaliko.com/2011/08/jquery-ui-dialog-aspnet-postback.html

**Update 1:**

To make all happy, the solution is to register the modal into the form:

```
var myDialog = jQuery("#myDialog").dialog({ width: 480, height: 400 });
myDialog.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
```

Comment: The same answer already exist. Please have a look to our FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Additionally, at Stack Overflow it is customary to post the solution and then cite sources. You need to move the conclusion from the web page onto this page.